# Random Items and linking

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

Sorry if the post was unclear, I’ll try to explain as best I can. I’m creating a social psychology experiment online, and I need a function to be able to select at random different names (like John, Mike, Alex etc.). While looking for help online I found this code:

```
function swapImages(){
  var $active = $('#myGallery .active');
  var $next = ($('#myGallery .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#myGallery.active').next() : $('#myGallery img:first');
  $active.fadeOut(function(){
  $active.removeClass('active');
  $next.fadeIn().addClass('active');
  });})
```

Using this code and the "mousetrap" library I was able to change the name when a key is pressed. But I have no clue on how I can make the names appear randomly (this means, not in the order they are on the code, but different every time I do it). And after 40 different names, I need to link to another html page.

Thanks for the help, and sorry if my last post was confusing.... This is my first approach to programing :)

Old post:
Im quite new to the programing world, i need some help making this code select random items, not in the order I put them on. Also, i got this from the web and i need it to stop after 40 items and link to antoher page.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simple need to select random names - selection from array using Math.Random is the simplest approach:

```
var names = ["John", "Mike", "Peter", "Sid", "Homer"]
var idx;

do {
    idx = parseInt(names.length * Math.random());
    alert(names[idx]);
    names.splice(idx, 1);
} while (names.length > 0)
```

Basically it generates random index within boundaries of array's length, selects element at that index and then removes the element from array. Loop exits when there're no more elements to display.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4NNTA/1/

If your list has over 40 items and you need to exit after 40 - add a counter and condition to the `while`. After exiting the loop you can redirect to another page by setting `location.href` to URL of page you want to go to.

***UPDATE*** This is a function that used revised code above. It lets you specify arbitrary number of names:

```
    var Names = function () {

        var data;
        var counter;

        function initData() {
            data = ["John", "Mike", "Peter", "Sid", "Homer"]
        }

        this.init = function (c) {
            counter = c;
            initData()
        }

        this.getName = function () {

            if (counter === 0) {
                return ""
            } else {

                if (data.length === 0) initData();

                var idx = parseInt(data.length * Math.random());
                var sName = data[idx]
                data.splice(idx, 1);

                counter--;
                return sName

            }
        }
    }
```

Inside of `function initData` you can specify array of names. Then you initialize it by passing number of names you want to display (this example initializes it to 40):

```
var myNames = new Names();
myNames.init(40);
```

And then every time you call

```
myNames.getName()
```

It will give you next random name. The names will not repeat until data is exhausted - then the array is reinitialized and random un-repeated names begin again. When all 40 names are retrieved - function returns empty string, which you can check and act accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the help. Just two things i dont get, what if i have less than 40 names ?

Comment: If you have less that 40 names then condition `while (names.length > 0)` will exist the loop when all the names are gone - this is what example above does - it exits when all 5 names are shown

Comment: sorry, i dont know why the coment was incomplete when i posted it.

   thanks for the help. Just two things i dont get, what if i have less than 40 names (but still need 40 names to appear)? And how do i ask JS to only give me one name every time i call the function ?

Comment: Gotcha. I've update my code by posting function you can call.